# Arranging The html Tables using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, jquery-selectors

Lets say I have this table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
    <tr>
        <th><h1>Tracks</td></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Track Id</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th>Track Name</th>
        <th>Uploader</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Artist 1</td>
        <td>Track Name 1</td>
        <td>Uploader 1</td>
        <td>Blocked</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Artist 2</td>
        <td>Track Name 2</td>
        <td>Uploader 2</td>
        <td>Visible</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Through JQuery how would arrange the table rows depending on their value? lets say I want to show table rows that only contains  a table data value. How would I do that through Jquery?

Comment: Well, if you give specify what sort of filter you'd like to use, and the end-result of that filter (given that the above code seems to have no 'data values'), then that would help us to give you an answer, rather than mere speculation.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by table data value, is it where the first `td` in a `tr` contains a number or is it some sort of other value, right now it's hard to understand what it is you are trying to do?

Comment: it is where a <td> contains a number or any value that I type in the search box. lets say I am only  searching for a <tr> where it has a <td>Visible</td> it will only return rows or a <tr> that has a <td> containg the value "Visible"

Comment: Would you be willing to use a [plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)?

Comment: It would be better if I am going to do it without any plugin

Comment: Then I will refer to @MoinZaman's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
$('#search').on('keyup', function() {
    var val = $.trim(this.value).toLowerCase();
    $('table > tbody > tr:gt(1)').hide();
    if (val.length) {
        $('table > tbody > tr:gt(1) > td').filter(function() {
            return this.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) >= 0;
        }).parent().show();
    } else  $('table > tbody > tr:gt(1)').show();
});
```

*( this will give you some guideline )*

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QK9Vy/3/)**

---

**Related refs:**

- **[.gt()](http://api.jquery.com/gt)**
- **[parent > child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)**
- **[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter)**

Comment: what does this do? "$('table > tbody > tr').hide();" ?

Comment: @user962206 it hides all `tr`s (direct children of table)? and I changed that. not it will hide all `tr`s accept first one with `Track`

Comment: the thing it it also hides table headers

Comment: @SperanskyDanil using `.each()` two times is slower

Comment: @user962206 it will select all `tr` with index greater that `1` and I share necessary links, check them and you will get answer, mate

Comment: Just to let to make it clear this line when this line is executed 
  $('table > tbody > tr:gt(1)').hide(); it will hide all tr s? am I correct?

Comment: but what's the use tr:gt(1) is it really necessary?

Comment: @thecodeparadox what does this do ? 'table > tbody > tr:gt(1) > td' ?

Answer (score 1):

***As a variant ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Y37Wu/3/)):***

HTML

```
<input id="search" type="text">

<table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
    <tr>
        <th>Track Id</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th>Track Name</th>
        <th>Uploader</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Artist 1</td>
        <td>Track Name 1</td>
        <td>Uploader 1</td>
        <td>Blocked</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Artist 2</td>
        <td>Track Name 2</td>
        <td>Uploader 2</td>
        <td>Visible</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

​JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#search').keyup(function () {
        $('#table tr').show();
        var q = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

        $('#table tr:not(:first)').each(function () {
            var visible = false;

            $('td', this).each(function () { 
                var content = $(this).text().toLowerCase();                    
                if (content.indexOf(q) != -1) visible = true;
            });

            $(this).toggle(visible);
        });
    })
});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Y37Wu/3/)